# Adding comma after each word in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, magicsuggest

I have selected tag input and I can choose multiple items using [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/) plugin.

The problem is that the value that I get after the choice is a string separated without a comma.

**Like:**

> MVCPHPASP.Net

**I want to change it to:**

> MVC,PHP,ASP.Net

The result that I get when I choose multiple items : 
[image]

The string that I get when I alert :

[image]

So how can I do that?

Comment: You don't, unless you have very specific words you are looking for. Almost every tag component offers some form of serialization that will do this for you. Since you don't say which one you're using, there's no way to know how that particular one does it. It's more likely you're just grabbing a raw array and not using `join`.

Comment: It would be very useful if you could show us html and javascript relative to this question, that you are using.

Comment: [Here](http://prntscr.com/9x6j3l) it's my js file to get the string inside that textbox
[Here](http://prntscr.com/9x6jfo) it's my js file using magic suggest
[Here](http://prntscr.com/9x6jqs) it's my html file to display magic suggest

Comment: As i understand, your values are predefined strings. Would it possible to append those values with "," ? For example: instead of "MVC" you could have "MVC," ?

Comment: yes @blindProgrammer how can i do that

Comment: Could you please show us where those values are coming from? I want to see HTML part ot this control.

Comment: @blindProgrammer [Here](http://prntscr.com/9x6stf) it's html i'm using [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest) and that why we got this html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The right way is to get the data using the plugin's API, not weird parsing**.

According the [docs](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html#desc-getValue) you can use the function `.getSelection()` to get the selected items.

```js
var ms = $('#ms-getValue').magicSuggest({
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Paris'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'New York'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Gotham'
    } 
  ]
});

function getValues() {
  // array
  var selected = ms.getSelection();
  alert(selected.map(function(item) {
    return item.name;
  }).join(','));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/lib/magicsuggest/magicsuggest.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/lib/magicsuggest/magicsuggest.js"></script>

<div id="ms-getValue"></div>
<button onclick="getValues()">Get Values</button>
```

**Update** The result is an `Array`. So, to get the first (for example) selected object you do: `selected[0].name`

**Update 2**

To show all the selected values separated by comma:

```js
selected.map(function(item) {
  return item.name;
}).join(',')
```

Comment: [Here](http://prntscr.com/9x7brr) it's the result i get so how can i get the name

Comment: So how we can get current index if i choice more than one item

Comment: `current index`.. What do you want, to show the all selected item's names separated with comma?

Comment: Fu  yes i  want show the all selected item's names separated with comma

Comment: I just was updated my answer. Let me know if it's OK.

Comment: My pleasure. Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer so it will help to other people..